# Publish Java artifact to Maven Local with Gradle

Tags: maven, gradle, publish, artifact, maven-publish

I am facing a problem when trying to install a generated jar into my local Maven Repository. The message error just show me 'task 'publish' is not found'

I am using this Gradle Script:

```
buildscript {
    ext {
        springBootVersion = '1.3.2.RELEASE'
    }
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-gradle-plugin:${springBootVersion}") 
    }
}

apply plugin: 'java'
apply plugin: 'eclipse'
apply plugin: 'idea'
apply plugin: 'spring-boot'
apply plugin: 'maven-publish'

jar {
    baseName = 'mongofoundry'
    version = '1.0.0'
}
sourceCompatibility = 1.7
targetCompatibility = 1.7


repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}


dependencies {
    compile('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web')
    compile('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-mongodb')
    testCompile('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test') 
}

publishing {
    publications {
        mavenJava(MavenPublication) {
            from components.java
        }
    }
}


eclipse {
    classpath {
         containers.remove('org.eclipse.jdt.launching.JRE_CONTAINER')
         containers 'org.eclipse.jdt.launching.JRE_CONTAINER/org.eclipse.jdt.internal.debug.ui.launcher.StandardVMType/JavaSE-1.7'
    }
}

task wrapper(type: Wrapper) {
    gradleVersion = '2.9'
}
```

Do you have some idea Why I am reading that error message?
Thanks.

**UPDATED**

Running the command as @RaGe mentioned, solved the problem:

```
gradle publishToMavenLocal
```

Comment: Try `gradle publishToMavenLocal`

Comment: in early days 'gradle install' worked just fine...

Comment: @AdamSkywalker that is with the now deprecated `maven` plugin. `maven-publish` changes a few things around.

Comment: @RaGe thanks, I'll take a look

Comment: You could add `task install(dependsOn: publishToMavenLocal)` if you have particularly strong habits.

Comment: Thank you everybody, I solved the problem running the task publishToMavenLocal as @Rage mentioned, but using the dependency way as EricWendelin mentioned, it is a nice way to do, So I have implemented the way he advice. Thank you guys. =)

Comment: Why not use     `apply plugin: 'maven'` and `gradle install`?

Comment: @RaGe Are there any features that Gradle ISN'T planning on deprecating? That's what I'd like to know... :P

Answer (score 152, accepted):

The correct task to publish artifacts to local maven is

```
gradle publishToMavenLocal
```

Comment: This actually doesn't work the way I want. The artifact should have been placed in C:\Users\XXXX\.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\cdb-webservices-spring-boot-starter  but it gets placed in C:\Users\XXXX\.m2\repository\cdb-webservices-spring-boot-starter\cdb-webservices-spring-boot-starter\

Comment: @VinayakDornala See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35460534/gradle-is-it-possible-to-publish-to-gradles-own-local-cache

Comment: I just wanted to add that I sometimes find it helpful to customize the version number when publishing directly from the command line -- you can do this by adding `-Pversion=<whatever>`. IE `gradle publishToMavenLocal -Pversion=SNAP`

Answer (score 11):

**Check Maven locally**

For developing and testing it is useful to check library locally

`gradle` settings for `apply plugin: 'com.android.library'` not `apply plugin: 'java-library'`(where you can use it by  default)

```
apply plugin: 'maven-publish'

//simple settings
project.afterEvaluate {
    publishing {
        publications {
            library(MavenPublication) {
                //setGroupId groupId
                setGroupId "com.company"
                //setArtifactId artifactId
                setArtifactId "HelloWorld"
                version "1.1"

                artifact bundleDebugAar

/* add a dependency into generated .pom file
                pom.withXml {
                    def dependenciesNode = asNode().appendNode('dependencies')
                    def dependencyNode = dependenciesNode.appendNode('dependency')
                    dependencyNode.appendNode('groupId', 'com.company')
                    dependencyNode.appendNode('artifactId', 'HelloWorld-core')
                    dependencyNode.appendNode('version', '1.1')

                }
*/
            }
        }
    }
}
```

to run it using command line or find this command in `Gradle` tab

```
./gradlew publishToMavenLocal
```

**Location**

artefact will be added into `.m2` folder

```
//Unix
~/.m2

//Windows
C:\Users\<username>\.m2

//For example
/Users/alex/.m2/repository/<library_path>/<version>/<name>.<extension>
```

`build` folder

```
<project_path>/build/outputs/<extension>
```

other repositories location

```
~/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/<group_id>/<artifact_id>/<version>/<id>

//For example
/Users/alex/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/com.company/HelloWorld/1.1/c84ac8bc425dcae087c8abbc9ecdc27fafbb664a
```

To use it add `mavenLocal()`. It is important to place it as a first item for prioritise it, which is useful for internal dependencies

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        mavenLocal()
    }

allprojects {
    repositories {
        mavenLocal()
    }
}
```

and

```
dependencies {
    implementation 'com.company:HelloWorld:+'
}
```

*Also remember if you use a kind of `shared.gradle` file (via `apply from`) you should set **path** which is relevant to `project.gradle` (**not** `shared.gradle`)

[[iOS CocoaPod local]](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57812997/4770877)

Answer (score 7):

Here is an alternative skeleton for **Gradle 7.5.1** with **Java 17**

**build.gradle**

```
plugins {
    id 'org.gradle.java'
    id 'org.gradle.maven-publish'
}

repositories {
    mavenLocal()
    mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
}

java {
    toolchain {
        languageVersion = JavaLanguageVersion.of(17)
    }
    withJavadocJar()
    withSourcesJar()
}

publishing {
    publications {
        mavenJava(MavenPublication) {
            groupId = 'your-group'
            artifactId = 'your-artifact'
            version = "0.0.1"
            from components.java
        }
    }
    repositories {
        mavenLocal()
    }
}
```

**Publishing**

You can see more details on the publishing steps with `--info`

```
./gradlew --info publishToMavenLocal
```

**Output Directory**

Linux/macOS

```
/Users/<username>/.m2/repository/your-group/your-artifact/0.0.1
```

Windows

```
C:\Users\<username>\.m2\repository\your-group\your-artifact\0.0.1
```

Comment: Only with this step works: 

publishing {
    publications {
        mavenJava(MavenPublication) {
            groupId = 'your-group'
            artifactId = 'your-artifact'
            version = "0.0.1"
            from components.java
        }
    } ...
Thank you!

Answer (score 5):

This is how I did it with [Kotlin DSL](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/kotlin_dsl.html) (build.gradle.kts) for [my Android library](https://github.com/mahozad/android-pie-chart):

```kotlin
plugins {
    id("maven-publish")
    // OR simply
    // `maven-publish`

    // ... (other plugins)
}

publishing {
    repositories {
        // Local repository which we can first publish in it to check artifacts
        maven {
            name = "LocalTestRepo"
            url = uri("file://${buildDir}/local-repository")
        }
    }
    publications {
        // ...
    }
}
```

You can create all the publications with the following command:

```bash
./gradlew publishAllPublicationsToLocalTestRepoRepository
```

Or just a single publication with this command:

```bash
./gradlew publishReleasePublicationToLocalTestRepoRepository
```

See [Gradle documentations: Maven Publish Plugin](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/publishing_maven.html) for more information.

Answer (score 2):

Add [maven plugin](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/maven_plugin.html) to your project and then:
`gradle clean install`

Comment: do you have to install a plugin to get "install"

Comment: No. You could do what @Eric Wendelin suggested in one of the comments to the question.