# Gradle: is it possible to publish to Gradle's own local cache?

Tags: gradle

I know that I can use the `maven` plugin coupled with `mavenLocal()` to install an artifact and use it locally.

However investigating this a bit further, I notice that this means the artifacts are installed to Mavens's standard `~/.m2`, but at the same time Gradle's own cache lives under `~/.gradle/caches` in a different format.

This seems wasteful to me, a) working with two local caches, and b) having to add `mavenLocal()` to all projects. I was wondering if there is a way to publish an artifact to Gradle's `~/.gradle/caches` ?

Answer (score 32, accepted):

Note that the local Maven repository is not (really) a cache, and that the Gradle cache is not a repository. Gradle uses its cache only to cache remote artifacts, it should not copy artifacts retrieved from local Maven repositories there. In turn, [you cannot publish artifacts to the Gradle cache](https://discuss.gradle.org/t/what-is-the-preferred-gradle-approach-to-locally-install-an-artifact-equivalent-to-mavens-install/5592/3).

So the approach to publish to and use `mavenLocal()` should not be as wasteful as you think. Also, you do not have to add `mavenLocal()` to all projects of a multi-project separately. You can simply use something like `allprojects { repositories { mavenLocal() } }` in your root project. Or if you want `mavenLocal()` in *all* your independent Gradle projects you could even try adding it to `~/.gradle/init.gradle`.

Comment: Well this is for an internal build plugin so `allprojects` won't work because I'm adding `mavenLocal()` to `buildscript`. But this does answer the question.

Comment: But the question remains. How do you push to (or at least invalidate) Gradle's cache?

Comment: Depending on your exact use-case, [--refresh-dependencies](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/command_line_interface.html#sec:command_line_execution_options) might do what you want.

Comment: init.gradle (or init.gradle.kts for Kotlin)

Answer (score 3):

Here is an example with code. 
As it's not possible to publish into Gradle. The workaround is to publish into the maven and use it in Gradle.

Step 1 publish the code to local maven repository /users/jay/.m2/repository/

Step2 - Use the local maven repo code in another project.

Step #1 (Publish to local maven repo)

```
apply plugin: 'maven-publish'

publishing {
    publications {
        mavenJava(MavenPublication) {
            from components.java
        }
    }
}
```

Step #2 (Use the local maven repo in your gradle project)

```
repositories {

    // ..... Other repositories

    mavenLocal()
}


dependencies {
    compile 'com.jai:myapp:1.0.0'
}
```

Comment: for some reason the -plain, sources, javadoc get generated but not the actual jar file. Any idea what I would be missing?