# publishToMavenLocal -Pversion does not change version

Tags: android, maven, gradle

I try to change the version while publishing a android project to my local maven repository.
Simple publishing works fine with`./gradlew publishToMavenLocal`.

While researching I found out that it should be possible to override the version number of my maven package on executing the publishing process. But when executing for example `publishToMavenLocal -Pversion="asdf"` this does not change the version in anyway. it seems like it is ignored.

I got the idea of the `-Pversion` flag from the comments of [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35094655/publish-java-artifact-to-maven-local-with-gradle#_=_)
Furthermore also the gradle docs say that it should be possible to override the version in some way when building it:

> Overriding the default identity values is easy: simply specify the
>   groupId, artifactId or version attributes when configuring the
>   MavenPublication.

i don't know if i got anything wrong but is there a way to override the version of a maven package. Also publishing something like `-SNAPSHOT` to my **local maven** repo would help me a lot.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you're not already specifying a version in your build.gradle file, otherwise the flag version won't be applied. Tested with Gradle version 7.6.1.

Answer (score 0):

It works for me with Gradle 7.6.

```
$./gradlew publishToMavenLocal -Pversion=31
...
BUILD SUCCESSFUL in 1s
21 actionable tasks: 18 executed, 3 up-to-date

$ls -al ~/.m2/repository/com/foo/bar/client
total 8
drwxr-xr-x  4 johnkramer  staff  128 Jan 26 18:05 .
drwxr-xr-x  5 johnkramer  staff  160 Jan 26 18:05 ..
drwxr-xr-x  6 johnkramer  staff  192 Jan 26 18:05 31
-rw-r--r--  1 johnkramer  staff  334 Jan 26 18:05 maven-metadata-local.xml
```